# C# LINQ - Group List by a property then select by different groups

Tags: c#, .net, linq, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

I have a list that I want to group by property `A`. Then select all the elements for that group where the `GroupBy` key is `null` or `''` then I want to return all the elements for those groups. Otherwise, for a group key return the first element of that group. I have come up with the following and what I expect from code. Any help would be much appreciated.

Sample code:

```
public class ABC
{
    public string A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }
    public string C { get; set; }
}

var list = new List<ABC>()
{
    new ABC() { A = "a", B = "b", C = "c" },
    new ABC() { A = "a", B = "b", C = "c" },
    new ABC() { A = null, B = "b", C = "c" },
    new ABC() { A = null, B = "b", C = "c" },
    new ABC() { A = "", B = "b", C = "c" },
    new ABC() { A = "", B = "b", C = "c" },
};

var result = list.GroupBy(x => x.A)
                 .Select(x => 
                 {
                     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Key))
                        return x.First();
                     else
                        return x;
                 })
                 .ToList();
```

What I expect:

I am expecting to see a total of `5` count from the result

```
{ A = "a", B = "b", C = "c" } count 1 (1 removed)
{ A = null, B = "b", C = "c" } count 2 (none removed)
{ A = "", B = "b", C = "c" } count 2 (none removed)
```

Comment: In your `Select` you can modify it to return lists (where some lists will only contain one item), something like: `var result = list.GroupBy(x => x.A).Select(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Key) ? x.ToList() : new List<ABC> { x.First() }).ToList();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
 var result = list
   .GroupBy(item => item.A)
   .SelectMany(group => string.IsNullOrEmpty(group.Key)
      ? group as IEnumerable<ABC>
      : new ABC[] {group.First()})
   .ToList();
```

The trick here is that we should return *collection*: either entire group or a collection (array) with the `First` item only.

You can get rid of *grouping* and *flatten* to have a faster version which, however, exploits *side effect*:

```
 HashSet<string> uniqueA = new HashSet<string>(); 

 var result = list
   .Where(item => string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.A) || uniqueA.Add(item.A))
   .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

A few pointers:

- Optional, but consider a ternary operator instead of if/else.
- If `IsNullOrEmpty` is false, instead of using `First`, use `Where` and filter for index of '0' so that it stays in list form, even though it only has one item in it.
- Use `SelectMany` instead of `Select` to flatten the results

Here are the pointers in action:

```
var result = 
    list
    .GroupBy(x => x.A)
    .SelectMany(x => 
        string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Key)
        ? x
        : x.Where((val,ix) => ix == 0)
    )
    .ToList();
```

A LINQPad Dump of this using your sample data produces:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | b | c |
| null | b | c |
| null | b | c |
|  | b | c |
|  | b | c |

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = list.GroupBy(x => x.A)
                .Select(g =>
                    new
                    {
                        Key = g.Key,
                        Values = string.IsNullOrEmpty(g.Key) ? g.ToList() : new List<ABC> {g.FirstOrDefault()}
                    })
                .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have to use LINQ? The answer by @pwilcox is fine but you might find something like this more readable:

```
var newList = new List<ABC>();
var setOfA = new HashSet<string>();
        
foreach (var abc in list)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(abc.A))
    {
        newList.Add(abc);
    }
    else
    {
        if (setOfA.Contains(abc.A))
        {
            continue;
        }

        setOfA.Add(abc.A);
        newList.Add(abc);
    }
}
```